# What does this AC power connector symbol mean?

Tags: power, connector, symbol

I've seen this on the wall-facing side of many (North American) AC power connectors.

What is it called? 
What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: [Related question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53636/what-does-the-clock-like-symbols-under-plastic-containers-mean).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a kind of datecode. The mold for the plug actually has a small part that can be rotated with a screwdriver, to point the arrow at different numbers around the perimeter of the circle. They do this to either indicate a new month of manufacture, or perhaps a revision number.

Note the 1 and the 3 on either side of the arrow. In this case, it's a datecode indicating the third month of 2013. Once a month, they rotate the arrow, and once a year, they replace the rotating part altogether with one for the next year.

Comment: In addition.  This kind of mark can be found on all sorts of injection molded parts, not only plugs.